# IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: '\x89PNG\n'

Tags: python, image, ioerror

I just started to program (with Python) because I needed to develop a kind of executable that allows me to perform diameter distributions. I managed to get to something that works (code below):

```
# Put here all modules you would need in order to represent your data

import matplotlib.pylab as plt 
import numpy as np
import collections as c
from collections import Counter
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import Tkinter as tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

# This prints the plot containing the diameter distribution of our sample

root = tk.Tk() ; root.withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename(parent=root)
f = open(filename)

with f as input: #Change the Results.txt file for your own .txt file
    a = zip(*(line.strip().split('\t') for i,line in enumerate(input) if i != 0))

areas = a[1]

diam = []
for area in areas:
    diam.append(round((np.sqrt(float(area)/ np.pi) * 2), 3)) # The number 3 tells us how many decimals will be shown
hist, bins = np.histogram(diam, 50)
diam.sort()

counts = c.Counter(diam)

'''This prints the table which includes all diameter values 
and how many of them we can find on our sample# '''

table = sorted(counts.items()) 
col_labels = ['Diameter (nm)', 'Counts'] # In Diameter column you can add the units inside the empty parenthesis
table_vals = table

q = diam

mu = sum(q)/float(len(q))
variance = np.var(q)
sigma = np.sqrt(variance)

# In the plt.suptitle part --> change the default name to your sample name

plt.subplot(121)
plt.bar(counts.keys(), counts.values(), 0.01, color="black")
plt.tick_params(direction = 'out', labeltop='off', labelright='off')
plt.xlabel('Diameter (nm)', fontsize=16, fontweight='bold')
plt.ylabel('Count (a.u.)', fontsize=16, fontweight='bold')
plt.title(r'$\mathregular{Diameter \ distribution\ of \ the\ sample:}\ \mu=%.3f,\ \sigma=%.3f$' % (mu, sigma), fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')
plt.suptitle('Silicon nanopillars grown epitaxially', fontsize=22, fontweight='bold')
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=None)

the_table = plt.table(cellText = table_vals, colLabels = col_labels, loc = 'bottom', cellLoc = 'center', bbox = [0.67, 0.18, 0.30, 0.8])
the_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
the_table.set_fontsize(12)

# This adds a gaussian fit to our histogram

plt.plot()

x = diam

yhist, xhist = np.histogram(x, bins=np.arange(4096))

xh = np.where(yhist > 0)[0]
yh = yhist[xh]

def gaussian(x, a, mu, sigma):
return a * np.exp(-((x - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2)))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(gaussian, xh, yh, [1, mu, sigma]) 

i = np.linspace(min(diam)-20, max(diam), 1000) 
plt.plot(i, gaussian(i, *popt), lw=3, ls=':', c='r')
plt.xlim(min(diam)-10, max(diam)+10)

# This adds the image from where the data is extracted (always use .png images otherwise this won't work)

im = Image.open('Dosi05.png') # Put here the original image
im2 = Image.open('Dosi05_Analyzed.png') # Put here the thresholded and analysed image

plt.subplot(222)
plt.imshow(im, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('Original Image', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold') 

plt.subplot(224)
plt.imshow(im2, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('Processed Image', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')


plt.show()
```

But I was asked to do the same that is done with the .txt file but with the images ploted using plt.subplot(222) and plt.subplot(224) in order to avoid touching the code.

I tried by doing something similar also using Tkinter (see code below):

```
# Put here all modules you would need in order to represent your data

import matplotlib.pylab as plt 
import numpy as np
import collections as c
from collections import Counter
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import Tkinter as tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename, askopenfile
from skimage import data

# This prints the plot containing the diameter distribution of our sample

root = tk.Tk() ; root.withdraw()
filename = askopenfilename(parent=root)
f = open(filename)

with f as input: #Change the Results.txt file for your own .txt file
    a = zip(*(line.strip().split('\t') for i,line in enumerate(input) if i != 0))

areas = a[1]

diam = []
for area in areas:
    diam.append(round((np.sqrt(float(area)/ np.pi) * 2), 3)) # The number 3 tells us how many decimals will be shown
hist, bins = np.histogram(diam, 50)
diam.sort()

counts = c.Counter(diam)

'''This prints the table which includes all diameter values 
and how many of them we can find on our sample# '''

table = sorted(counts.items()) 
col_labels = ['Diameter (nm)', 'Counts'] # In Diameter column you can add the units inside the empty parenthesis
table_vals = table

q = diam

mu = sum(q)/float(len(q))
variance = np.var(q)
sigma = np.sqrt(variance)

# In the plt.suptitle part --> change the default name to your sample name

plt.subplot(121)
plt.bar(counts.keys(), counts.values(), 0.01, color="black")
plt.tick_params(direction = 'out', labeltop='off', labelright='off')
plt.xlabel('Diameter (nm)', fontsize=16, fontweight='bold')
plt.ylabel('Count (a.u.)', fontsize=16, fontweight='bold')
plt.title(r'$\mathregular{Diameter \ distribution\ of \ the\ sample:}\ \mu=%.3f,\ \sigma=%.3f$' % (mu, sigma), fontsize=18, fontweight='bold')
plt.suptitle('Silicon nanopillars grown epitaxially', fontsize=22, fontweight='bold')
plt.autoscale(enable=True, axis='x', tight=None)

the_table = plt.table(cellText = table_vals, colLabels = col_labels, loc = 'bottom', cellLoc = 'center', bbox = [0.67, 0.18, 0.30, 0.8])
the_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
the_table.set_fontsize(12)

# This adds a gaussian fit to our histogram

plt.plot()

x = diam

yhist, xhist = np.histogram(x, bins=np.arange(4096))

xh = np.where(yhist > 0)[0]
yh = yhist[xh]

def gaussian(x, a, mu, sigma):
    return a * np.exp(-((x - mu)**2 / (2 * sigma**2)))

popt, pcov = curve_fit(gaussian, xh, yh, [1, mu, sigma]) 

i = np.linspace(min(diam)-20, max(diam), 1000) 
plt.plot(i, gaussian(i, *popt), lw=3, ls=':', c='r')
plt.xlim(min(diam)-10, max(diam)+10)

# This adds the image from where the data is extracted (always use .png images otherwise this won't work)

image_formats = [('PNG','*.png')]
file_path_list = askopenfilename(filetypes=image_formats, initialdir='/', title='Please select a picture to analyze')

for file_path in file_path_list:
     image = data.imread(file_path) 
     image2 = data.imread(file_path) 

plt.subplot(222)
plt.imshow(image, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('Original Image', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold') 

plt.subplot(224)
plt.imshow(image2, cmap='gray')
plt.axis('off')
plt.title('Processed Image', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')

plt.show()
```

But after selecting the first image file, Python throws me the following:

[IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: '\x89PNG\n' [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B65Mj.png)

Can someone tell me what I can do to solve this or if there are other ways to display the images by picking the from the file browser instead of changing them in the code itself?

Hope the question is enough clear, thanks for your help in advance!

Y

Comment: could you provide the whole traceback here!

Comment: @praba230890 the traceback is in a picture, if you click the 1 next to the IOError description you will get to it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The retrun value of `askopenfilename` is a string. As you were traversing over a string (Probabily a path like `C:\Somepath\someimage.png`) you got the following error.

> Errno2: No such file or directory: u'C'

You need to use the `askopenfilenames` module to get multiple files.

```
image_formats = [('PNG','*.png')]
file_path_list = askopenfilenames(filetypes=image_formats, initialdir='/', title='Please select a picture to analyze')
for file_path in file_path_list:
    file_path = os.path.normpath(file_path)  # To normalize path 
    image = data.imread(file_path) 
    image2 = data.imread(file_path)
```

Use `for file_path in file_path_list.split()` for python<2.7.7, as the return value was a [string instead of tuple](https://bugs.python.org/issue5712).

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath

---

**Orignal Question**

Op had pasted code with `askopenfile` instead of `askopenfilename`

[`tkFileDialog.askopenfile`](http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog) returns selected file opened in `r` mode if `mode` is not specified.

```
def askopenfile(mode = "r", **options):
    "Ask for a filename to open, and returned the opened file"

    filename = Open(**options).show()
    if filename:
        return open(filename, mode)
    return None
```

While the input to `imread` is image file path.
You need to use `askopenfilenames` which returns selected files path.

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer, looks like I pasted here the wrong code. I used 'askopenfilename' and the same problem arises again. Also I'm not sure how is related your first part of the answer to my question, sorry if it is evident but as I stated I recently started programming (2 weeks ago) and things are quite difficult to understand for me.

Comment: Using `askopenfilename` will give you the path, but I can see that your traversing over a string when using `for file_path in file_path_list`. Can you please try with `askopenfilenames` with the changes I suggested or paste the output of `print file_path_list` for more clarity. The first part of my answer is the implementation of `askopenfile`. I mentioned it to show that the return value is a file handle. Anyways as you mentioned that you put the wrong code here, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: I changed what you've told me and now the error changed to Errno2: No such file or directory: u'C' 
(it's quite hard to take a screenshot of the error because the programming window closes as fast as it spawns).

Comment: It looks like there is some problem with your file path. Will it be possible to get the output of `print file_path_list` after `askopenfilenames`?

Comment: I think I got your problem. You are either not using the `split()` method in `for file_path in file_path_list.split():` or you are still using `askopenfilename(...)`. I have modified the answer to normalize the path. One more thing you need to take care is that **there are no spaces in the path**. Let me know if this solves the problem.

Comment: Hmm changed in the way shown on Multiple Files and now I got the following traceback: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Users\AGuerrero\Desktop\Python\Test Tkinter.py", line 86, in <module> for file_path in file_path_list.split():
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7 but I run it using Miniconda

Comment: Aah. They modified the output after [`2.7.7`](https://bugs.python.org/issue5712). Now's it's a tuple instead of single string.So you can remove the `split()`. I tried with my miniconda setup and it's working properly. If you are still getting some error, I will suggest you print the `file_path_list` and see what type of output it is and how you need to parse it.

Comment: Okay this works now! But only let me to chose 1 image, maybe I miss something?

Edit: It actually let me to pick more images but only the first one selected is displayed in both subplots.

Comment: That's great. From your code I can see that only the last image will be processed as other parts of your code are outside the loop.